# Bind aws sqs region camel

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, apache-camel

So I'm trying to access to the simple queue service with apache camel.

Java DSL approach works fine, but I try to work with xml configuration.

```
private AmazonSQS sqs;
sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials);
Region sqsRegion = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
sqs.setRegion(sqsRegion);
```

The code above works fine, but i decided to build bean.

```
<context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:/default.properties" />
    <bean name="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
                <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="region" value="com.amazonaws.regions.Region"/>
    </bean>
```

And I got an error

> Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to
>   required type [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] for property 'region';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [com.amazonaws.regions.Region] for property 'region': no matching
>   editors or conversion strategy found

I haven't found anything about configuration sqs via Spring xml. And sometimes I think that apache camel is outdated or nobody uses it with sqs. 
Moreover the next step is to connect Extended SQS library that works fine in Java DSL implementation, but I have no idea how to configure queue via xml.

**UPD:**

Thanks to @jbird, I solved the problem in this way:

```
<context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:/default.properties" />
    <bean id="awsRegion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getRegion"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${aws.region}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
                <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="region" ref="awsRegion"/>
    </bean>
```

So, I just parsed my `default.properties` file that contains aws.key, aws.secret and region settings.

And I got the next problem. Apache camel stop running after loading routers and so on.

```
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[aws-sqs://queue?amazonSQSClient=%23sqsClient]
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 6.105 seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Router:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() {
        from("aws-sqs://queue?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient")
                .log("We have a message! ${body}")
                .to("file:target/output?fileName=login-message-${date:now:MMDDyy-HHmmss}.json");
    }
}
```

And the camel-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       ">

    <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:/default.properties" />

    <bean id="awsRegion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getRegion"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${aws.region}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
                <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="region" ref="awsRegion"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- enable Spring @Component scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.router"/>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <contextScan/>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question.

First:

To add property to your object I simply create new bean

```
 <bean id="awsRegion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="getRegion"/>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${aws.region}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And create the reference

```
<property name="region" ref="awsRegion"/>
```

Second:

To run Apache Camel

```
Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("/META-INF/spring/camel-contex.xml");
        main.run(args);
```

Thats all!

Comment: I'm getting an exception when I try to do this:

java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean@521b30d2 to type com.amazonaws.regions.Region

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `region` property is the String value `"com.amazonaws.regions.Region"`. It is expecting an object of type `com.amazonaws.regions.Region` instead. So you need to reference an object of type `Region` instead of providing a String value.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I resolve the issues (check the upd section), but got another problem.